# Handling Errors Thrown By Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, error-handling

Let's say I have an object:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class SOClass {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private List<String> dataString;


    public SOClass(WebDriver driver) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        this.driver = driver;
        prepData();
    }

    private void prepData() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

        List<WebElement> data = this.driver.findElements(By.className("a-export-table"));
        if(data.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("There was no data in the table to export");
        }
        for(WebElement w : data) {
            this.dataString.add(w.getText());
        }
    }

    public void export(String path) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path);
        boolean isFirst = false;
        for(String s : this.dataString) {
            if(isFirst) {
                fw.append(s);
            } else {
                fw.append("," + s);
            }
        }
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();

    }
}
```

and main:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class SOMain {
    private static final String COMPUTER_NAME = System.getProperty("user.name");
    private static final String CHROME_PATH =
            "C:/Users/" + COMPUTER_NAME + "/selenium/chromedriver.exe";

    private static final String OUT_PATH =  "C:/Users/" + COMPUTER_NAME + "/output/export.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", CHROME_PATH);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("www.someurlexample.com");
        try {
            SOClass so = new SOClass(driver);
            so.export(OUT_PATH);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, barring any compilation issues (I made this up as an example) my code will catch any exceptions the SOClass is defined to throw. However, I was wondering if the table does not exist on the page and Selenium throws a NoSuchElementException, will my SOMain automatically catch this exception because of the

```
 } catch(Exception e) {
 }
```

block, or because the object is not specified to throw this error, SOMain will not handle this error and break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `catch` will handle every exception that inherits from the `Exception` class (and occurs in the `try` obviously), which means, including `NoSuchElementException` as you can see [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html) the hierarchy of it.

However, you need to distinguish *Checked Exceptions* and *Unchecked Exceptions* or Runtime Exceptions. As you can see `NoSuchElementException` extends `java.lang.RuntimeException` which means it's unchecked, therefore the compiler doesn't require you to handle it. But keep in mind that this runtime exception extends `java.lang.Exception` so your `catch` will catch it during runtime if it occurs.